# Maven: How to capture HTTPS traffic through Fiddler

Tags: java, maven, fiddler, capture, keytool

The challenge:
Capturing maven requests to package repository

Issues:

- Fiddler has a certificate that needs to be added to Java Home
- Proxy has to be added to settings.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings.xml in the .m2 folder needs to be configured with proxy against fiddler

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>http</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username/>
        <password/>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>8888</port>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
        <id>https</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <username/>
        <password/>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>8888</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

The Fiddler certificate needs to be exported and added to jssecacerts in JAVA_HOME ($JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security).

You create the fiddler certificate by using tools --> options -> https --> actions --> Export Root certificate to Desktop

Command to run (must be changed according to JAVA_HOME path):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\keytool" -importcert -file "<Your path to Fiddler certificate>\fiddler root.cert" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\lib\security\jssecacerts" -storepass changeit
```